# Angular 7 and form arrays error of cannot find a control with path

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am building a form group with an array inside of it, using `mat-table` data source.

I started by creating the table:

```
<form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" *ngIf="total>0" formArrayName="distribution">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ind_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.individual_id}}</td>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ind_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ind_name}}</td>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ind_status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ind. Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ind_status}}</td>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="project_kit">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Kits </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Kits</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="kit" id="kit" placeholder="Kit">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let pk of projectKit" [value]="pk.project_kit">{{pk.kit_name}} part of project
                {{pk.project_name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actual_date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actual Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="legacy">
            <mat-label>Actual Dist. Date</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="actual_date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Actual Date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="note">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Note </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="legacy">
            <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="note" matInput type="text" placeholder="Note">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="submit" color="warn" (click)="addDist(element)">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      }"></tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

And for the typescript:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      distribution: this.fb.array([
    this.createArray()
  ])
});
```

And createArray():

```
createArray(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      'note': new FormControl(''),
      'kit': new FormControl(''),
      'actual_date': new FormControl('')
    });
```

The first typescript is fired when the user upload a file:

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" role="form">
      <input #fileInput type="file" formControlName="upload" value="Upload Excel/CSV file"
        (change)="upload($event.target.files)" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" />
      <button mat-raised-button id="inputFile" color="accent" (click)="reset()">
        <mat-icon color="warn">cancel</mat-icon>Reset
      </button>
    </form>
```

There is no error for the previous form of uploading a file.

But when I upload a file an error appears for the form array:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'distribution -> 1'
>       at _throwError (forms.js:1790)
>       at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:1772)
>       at FormGroupDirective.push

And it's pointing on:

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Kits</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="kit" id="kit" placeholder="Kit">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let pk of projectKit" [value]="pk.project_kit">{{pk.kit_name}} part of project
                  {{pk.project_name}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
          </div>
```

**EDIT**

After Adding `{{formGroup.value| JSON}}` I got this:

> { "distribution": [ { "note": "", "kit": "", "actual_date": "" } ] }

Comment: try formGroupName without [] or [formGroup]

Comment: @Vato I tried it but still the same

Comment: try printing out formGroup on your page as json. put this somewhere in you html. {{ formGroup.value | json }}. it seems that the formArray stay's empty so It can't find anything at index 1.

Comment: I got this `{ "distribution": [ { "note": "", "kit": "", "actual_date": "" } ] }
`

Comment: @Vato should I at least specify a value on form group load ?

Comment: try using 0 instead of 1. just try to hardcode instead of using 'i' for now.

Comment: You have to define form array name above your form group start like this ```formArrayName="distribution" ```

Comment: @Vato it worked by replacing `i` with `0`, so I leave it like that ?

Comment: try i-1 for now. 0 will always point to first one. you want to point to the i-th in the array.

Comment: @Vato I got `Error: Cannot find control with path: 'distribution -> -1'` when using `i-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is your dataSource, let i=index make reference to the values of the dataSource, if you has less element in your array than in your dataSource your code crash

If all your elements in the table belongs to the FormArray it's "easy", you can see an example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zl9gdb?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

There are two keys,

one how create the Form

```
myform:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    distribution:new FormArray(ELEMENT_DATA.map(x=>{
      return new FormGroup({
      position:new FormControl(x.position),
      name:new FormControl(x.name),
      weight:new FormControl(x.weight),
      symbol:new FormControl(x.symbol),

    })}))
  });
```

And, how We refereed to the controls

```
<form *ngIf="myform" [formGroup]="myform">
  <ng-container formArrayName="distribution">
<!--see that datasource is myForm.get('distribution').controls-->
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myform.get('distribution').controls" class="mat-elevation-z8" >
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <!--so, "element" is a formGroup-->
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index" [formGroup]="element"> <input formControlName="position" > </td>
  </ng-container>
 ....
</table>
</ng-container>
</form>
```

But you has a "dataSource" and a formArray some disconected. You can create a function to referred to the array

```
get distributionArray()
{
   return this.myForm.get('distribution') as FormArray
}
```

And use in your td some like

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index" 
     [formGroup]="distributionArray.at(i)"> 
    <input formControlName="name" > 
</td>
```

}

well, it's not necesary has value to all, but must there are so many elements in the array as in the dataSource, e.g.

```
this.myform:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
        distribution:new FormArray(ELEMENT_DATA.map(()=>{
          //only two properties empty
          return new FormGroup({
          weight:new FormControl(),
          symbol:new FormControl(),

        })}))
      });
```

Or using push

```
this.myform:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
            distribution:new FormArray([])
});
ELEMENT_DATA.forEach(()=>{
    (this.myForm.get('distribution') as FormArray).push(this.createArray())
}
```

Comment: Sir, the control arrays are generated for each row in datasource and there is not data inside of them. Anyway I will give a try but with value empty for theb3 arrays

Comment: @alim1990, theb3 array can be all the controls value empty but must there are so many elements that the "dataSource", I updated my answer to show how do it

Answer (score -1):

Ok. so it means you're not adding enough formgroups in array. You are calling create only once. so only first one in array works. when the index goes to 1 from 0 there is no formgroup in formarray. As I understand you want to create formgroup for each row. so you need to call your function many times.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      distribution: this.fb.array([
    this.createArray()
  ])
});
```

instead of creating array every time you should probably push new formgroup to existing formarray.

write a getter for distribution for easier use.

```
get distribution() {
   this.formGroup.get('distribution') as FormArray;
}
```

then you can do

```
this.distribution.push(this.fb.group({
      'note': new FormControl(''),
      'kit': new FormControl(''),
      'actual_date': new FormControl('')
    }));
```

for each row. I'm not sure where you are doing create but this would go there for each row.

and keep the formGroup to i instead of i-1 or 0.

Comment: Can you check it with teamviewer ?

Answer (score -2):

You have to define form array name above your `[formGroup]` start like this `formArrayName="distribution"`

Comment: Where exactly ? Above each array ?

Comment: In td or ng-container wherever suitable

Comment: `Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).`

Comment: it need to be inside the formGroup. it is a child of it