# Generate HTML Form using ReactiveFormsModule angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am trying to build master APIs for the control panel. For that I need to generate the dynamic form in `.ts` file. Let me explain.

```
// Here is an array for generate 3 inut fields
const UserFields = [
    {
        name : 'name',
        type : 'text
    },
    {
        name : 'email',
        type : 'email
    },
    {
        name : 'password',
        type : 'text
    }
]
```

When I generate input filed in form using `*ngFor` and `FormGroup` its works fine. But in some cases, I need `N level` fields. In that case, I need to use `Recursive Function` to generate `HTML Form`

So I created `Recursive Function` and bind using `innerHTML` but the issue is that. `FormGrop` not working in that case.

Here is My `Recursive Function`

```
recursiveFields(formElement = ''){
    UserFields.map( (field : any)  => {
      // email or text or number
        formElement += `<input
        name="${field.name}" 
        type="${field.type}"
        [formControlName]="${field.name}" 
        class="form-control" />`;
      }
    });

    return formElement;
  }
```

`recursiveFields()` is working fine and generates HTML what I need. But After submit form I can't get value from `FormGrop`.

How can I achieve this Gole? Please help me. :)

Comment: Take a look at this question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352286/angular-deeply-nested-reactive-form-cannot-find-control-with-path-on-nested-for/62355590?noredirect=1#comment110679045_62355590

Comment: And also this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399246/6433166

Comment: And this blog post: https://dev.to/julianobrasil/writing-nested-recursive-angular-reactive-forms-a-clean-approach-57fk

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: @julianobrasil Thanks for your suggestion.  Let me check is it okay for me or not. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any chance to done using innerHTML?

Comment: I wouldn't take that path. It would be something like deconstruct everything angular is doing for you. Instead of thinking in terms of innerHTML, try to move your paradigm to components and json data.